# Sorting menus defined through plugin.xml

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have certain sub-menus added to a menu via plugin.xml.
Now i want these sub-menus to be in alphabetical order irrespective of their order
defined in plugin.xml

is there a way to accomplish this ?

Eclipse does a similar thing with Window -> Show View
You can see all the sub-menus for views arranged in alphabetical order.

Thanks,
Shashank

Comment: Why can't you define those menus in plugin.xml, so that they appear in alphabetical order? Or why cant you create your menu programmatically, so that items are sorted?

Comment: 1. Why can't you define those menus in plugin.xml, so that they appear in alphabetical order [Shashank] I don't want to enforce the same(alphabetical order) while adding menus in plugin.xml.

2.Or why cant you create your menu programmatically, so that items are sorted? [Shashank] I want to display the same commands defined in menus at multiple places hence i have declared them in plugin.xml (common place) Since the handlers and other conditions like visibleWhen etc need to be same.

Comment: But you will still need to rearrange menu item programmatically. Try to obtain menu manager ((WorkbenchWindow)window).getMenuManager(). This has some useful methods, like removing contribution items, adding contribution items, and adding items to the specific position. So, remove items , calculate new position index and add again. Then call menuManager.update(); to refresh GUI. Hope this helps.